# "Failed to authorize caller, the caller wasn't owner of the device or one of the admin roles." microsoft-graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, intune

Cannot seem to get GraphAPI to query Bitlocker Recovery Keys out of PowerShell. Using an Azure AD App registration

```
Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
client_Id     = $ApplicationID
Client_Secret = $AccessSecret
} 

$headr = @{
Authorization = "Bearer $($token)"
'ocp-client-name' = ""
'ocp-client-version' = "1.2"
}

$ConnectGraph = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenatDomainName/oauth2/v2.0/token" `
-Method POST -Body $Body

$token = $ConnectGraph.access_token

$GrapGroupUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bitlocker/recoveryKeys'
(Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headr -Uri $GrapGroupUrl -Method Get)
```

Error:

````
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"odata.error\":{\"Code\":\"authorization_error\",\"Message\":{\"Lang\":\"en\",\"Value\":\"Failed to authorize caller, the caller wasn't owner of the device 
or one of the admin roles.\"},\"Values\":[{\"Item\":\"subCode\",\"Value\":\"error_authorization_request_denied\"},{\"Item\":\"requestId\",\"Value\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\"},{\"Item\":\"time\",\"Value\":\"2020-11-19T04:43:13.6957327Z\"}]}}",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-11-19T04:43:13",
      "request-id": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "client-request-id": "xxxxxx"
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Hi, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Rall, any update about this problem ? Did you vote up my comment ? I mean click the check mark beside my answer but not my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, the error was caused by incorrect grant type(grant flow). As we can see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bitlocker-list-recoverykeys?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) shows us this graph api requires **Delegated** permission `BitLocker.ReadBasic.All, BitLocker.Read.All`, and it doesn't support "**Application**" permission.
[image]

So we can't use client credential flow to get the access token, we need to use [username/password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow to do it. Please refer to my test in below screenshot.
[image]

After running the command, we can see the result don't show the error message.
[image]